# How can I view my HTTP or HTTPS request before I send it?

Tags: php, html, http, curl

I'm in the process of trying to better understand http, more specifically I want to get comfortable working with web based APIs. Some of the documentation I've read for specific API's mention that the API will expect to get an http request in exactly this format, with specific headers and content.

I'm trying to use php cURL, but googling around I haven't found a way (that I understand) simply print my http request to the screen or a text file rather than sending it. I want to make sure that the request I'm constructing looks how I intend it to, rather than just getting back a success or failure message from whatever server the request is sent to. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You should avoid `curl_*` at all costs. It's a truly awful API. I *strongly* suggest [Artax](http://rdlowrey.github.io/Artax/) instead. It implements HTTP manually instead of using curl under the hood (unlike all the faux-http clients written in php). Viewing your raw HTTP request message is as simple as: `$client = new Artax\Client; $client->setOption('verboseSend', TRUE); $client->request('http://google.com');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using Fiddler. Fiddler show RESPONSE and REQUEST HEADER. Other than that you can install some extension to your browser that shows HEADER, Firefox does have such extension I think it is called LiveHTTP... sorry didn't remember name.

For web debugging Fiddler is what you need http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: This question is asking about inspecting a *server side* HTTP request to another server.  While Fiddler *could* work for this, the entire rest of your answer is client-side oriented.  You should perhaps include an example of how to make cURL requests pass through Fiddler...